# how to carry out logistic regression and random forest to predict churn rate

Tags: r, svm, random-forest, logistic-regression

I am using following dataset: http://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/churn.data

And the variable description: http://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/churn.names

Ii did preliminary coding but I am really not able to make out how to perform a logistic regression and Random Forest techniques to this data to predict the importance of variables and churn rate.

```
nm <- read.csv("http://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/churn.names",
               skip=4, colClasses=c("character", "NULL"), header=FALSE, sep=":")[[1]]
nm
dat <- read.csv("http://www.sgi.com/tech/mlc/db/churn.data", header=FALSE, col.names=c(nm, "Churn"))
dat
View(dat)
View(dat)
library(survival)
s <- with(dat, Surv(account.length, as.numeric(Churn)))
model <- coxph(s ~ total.day.charge + number.customer.service.calls, data=dat[, -4])
summary(model)
plot(survfit(model))
```

Also I am not able to figure out how to use the model that I built in my further analysis.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any example code of what you're trying to do? What further analysis do you have planned? If you're just trying to run a logistic regression on the data, the general format is:

```
lr <- glm(Churn ~ international.plan + voice.mail.plan + number.vmail.messages
          + account.length, family = "binomial", data = dat)
```

Try `help(glm)` and `help(randomForest)`